# Should we raise TypeError if __richcmp__ only partially implemented?

Tags: python, cython, typeerror, comparator

I implemented the method `__richcmp__` for a Cython extension type (`cdef class`). Some comparison cases are undefined (for example `<`), so I used to raise an `Exception` for them, [as follows](https://github.com/johnyf/dd/blob/82aba3ab5d01cbd2db420719f7e00b72b2a3f31d/dd/cudd.pyx#L1427).

```
def __richcmp__(Function self, Function other, op):
    if other is None:
        eq = False
    else:
        # guard against mixing managers
        assert self.manager == other.manager
        eq = (self.node == other.node)
    if op == 2:
        return eq
    elif op == 3:
        return not eq
    else:
        raise TypeError('Only `__eq__` and `__ne__` defined.')
```

I want to `pprint` containers of instances of this Cython class. [`pprint` attempts to compare](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6a7b3a77b4b2be0badd24ee5f0fdbaa2e0e79c3d/Lib/pprint.py#L89) them, except for a `TypeError`. My understanding is that as `TypeError`, `pprint` anticipates the case of undefined `__lt__`, or the case of different types of objects (see also [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)).

However, `__richcmp__` *is* implemented, so Python doesn't raise a `TypeError`. It calls `__richcmp__`, I raise an `Exception`, and that isn't ignored by `pprint`. Cython [requires](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/39df7ffd992e98fc8e15acd1741aeee751963fe5/docs/src/userguide/special_methods.rst#rich-comparisons) that `__richcmp__` be implemented, so I don't have the option of defining only `__eq__` and `__ne__`.

I changed my code to raising a `TypeError`. It seems that if Python communicates the lack of `__lt__` with a `TypeError`, then I should do the same, in order to signify that `__lt__` is absent, despite the presence of an entire `__richcmp__`, which was a byproduct of using Cython, not the design intent.

Does this reasoning make sense? Should I raise another kind of exception? Did I properly interpret the meaning of `TypeError` in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Cython is using your implementation as the C API [`tp_richcompare`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare). The documentation for that tells you

> If you want to implement a type for which only a limited set of comparisons makes sense (e.g. `==` and `!=`, but not `<` and friends), directly raise `TypeError` in the rich comparison function.

That gives you a fairly strong hint that it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Worth noting, for future visitors: the recommendation is now (as of 3.8) `NotImplemented`: https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare

Answer (score 0):

@DavidW provided a very precise and helpful answer, thank you. It points at how to approach similar future questions: by looking at the generated C code. I'm posting this answer as complimentary information for posterity.

Searching within the generated `cudd.c` file, we find the class signature:

```
static PyTypeObject __pyx_type_2dd_4cudd_Function = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(0, 0)
    "dd.cudd.Function", /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(struct __pyx_obj_2dd_4cudd_Function), /*tp_basicsize*/
    0, /*tp_itemsize*/
    ...
    ...
    __pyx_pw_2dd_4cudd_8Function_13__richcmp__, /*tp_richcompare*/
    ...
    ...
    #if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030400a1
    0, /*tp_finalize*/
    #endif
};
```

(The dots abbreviate lines irrelevant to our discussion.) The `PyTypeObject` is defined by the [CPython C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/type.html#c.PyTypeObject). The function `__pyx_pw_2dd` is defined later

```
/* "dd/cudd.pyx":1556
 *         return Cudd_DagSize(self.node)
 * 
 *     def __richcmp__(Function self, Function other, op):             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *         if other is None:
 *             eq = False
 */

/* Python wrapper */
static PyObject *__pyx_pw_2dd_4cudd_8Function_13__richcmp__(PyObject *__pyx_v_self, PyObject *__pyx_v_other, int __pyx_arg_op); /*proto*/
static PyObject *__pyx_pw_2dd_4cudd_8Function_13__richcmp__(PyObject *__pyx_v_self, PyObject *__pyx_v_other, int __pyx_arg_op) {
PyObject *__pyx_v_op = 0;
PyObject *__pyx_r = 0;
```

The way to find the first excerpt is by first searching the C file for the Python line of interest (here the signature of `Function.__richcmp__`), and then search for callers of the C function (though guided by this discussion, I found them by searching for `tp_richcompare`).

To confirm, I believe that Cython generates the first excerpt from [Cython/Compiler/TypeSlots.py](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/a0bbb940/Cython/Compiler/TypeSlots.py#L827):

```
# Later -- synthesize a method to split into separate ops?
MethodSlot(richcmpfunc, "tp_richcompare", "__richcmp__", inherited=False), # Py3 checks for __hash__
```

Interestingly, the comment there perhaps suggests that in the future users will be able to implement separate comparator methods, thus not encountering themselves directly this question.